# Placeholder not working in Chrome and Safari but working in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I encountered this issue today. I am using a placeholder for my search box. I have to keep it transparent until it is focused. It is working fine with Firefox. But Chrome and Safari doesn't show this placeholder when focused.

```css
#sv2 input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent
}

#sv2 input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent
}

input[type=search]:focus {
  width: 130px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #66cc75;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109, 207, 246, .5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109, 207, 246, .5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109, 207, 246, .5)
}
```

```html
<form method="get" action="https://www.example.com/" id="sv2">
  <input name="s" id="s" size="30" type="search" placeholder="Search example.com">
</form>
```

Thanks for your help and time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `::placeholder` to style the placeholder of the input text. This should be supported in all modern browsers.

Since this, and the `box-shadow` props are standardized, the latest versions of the browsers shouldn't need vendor prefixes for these rules.

```css
#sv2 input::placeholder {
  color: transparent
}

#sv2 input:focus::placeholder {
  color: gray
}

input[type=search]:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #66cc75;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109, 207, 246, .5);
}
```

```html
<form method="get" action="https://www.example.com/" id="sv2">
  <input name="s" id="s" size="30" type="search" placeholder="Search example.com">
</form>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!!! Thanks for quickest and perfect answer 